# Update datasource using Controllers(MVC) and Route Values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

We are working with Kendo-UI and ASP MVC.

When I define a Chart for the first time, I put the Action Name, Controller Name and Route Values:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
         .Read(read => read.Action("DataForEvo", "Home", new { seriename = "Default", category = "Default" }))
```

But later(at the client side), I need to reload the chart with new data.
I have 2 charts in the same page, at the bottom a "Bar Chart", and at the top a "Line Chart", when the user click any serie of the Bar Chart, the Line Chart should be updated with relative data.

In the "Bar Chart" I have the Series Click event:

```
.Events(ev => ev.SeriesClick("onSeriesClick")))
```

where I can get the serie name, category and value. From here using jquery I can get the chart

```
var Chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
```

and... maybe exist a method or way to call again the action with new 'route values'.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the read.Data() method to set a javascript function:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
     .Read(read => read.Data("SetData"))
```

The javascript function should return your data object:

```
function SetData() { return { seriesname: "Foo", category: "Bar" }; }
```